# Laravel Combobox AutoComplete Select2 JS

Tags: javascript, laravel, twitter-bootstrap, autocompletar, jquery-select2

Podem me ajudar?
Estou com o código mais abaixo funcionando perfeitamente.

Mas quando coloco dentro de um modal, não consigo escrever dentro do campo texto.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

## VIEW

```
<select class="itemName form-control" style="width:500px;" name="itemName" required></select>

<a href="#" id="rota" data-target="#modal" data-toggle="modal">Abrir chamado</a>
<div id="modal" class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <table class="table table-sm table-striped table-hover">
                    <tr>
                        <td><b>categoria:</b></td>
                        <td>
                            <select class="itemName form-control" style="width:500px;" name="itemName"></select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

## Controller

```
public function index()
    {
        $conteudo = Suporte::OrderBy('status', 'asc')->paginate();

        return view('suporte', ['conteudo' => $conteudo]);
    }

    public function dataAjax(Request $request)
    {
        $data = [];
        if($request->has('q')){
            $search = $request->q;
            $data = Categoria::select("id","categoria")
                    ->where('categoria','LIKE',"%$search%")
                    ->get();
        }
        return response()->json($data);
    }
```

## Rota

```
Route::get('/', 'suporteController@index');
Route::get('/select2-autocomplete-ajax', 'suporteController@dataAjax');
```

## JS

```
<script>
$('.itemName').select2({
        placeholder: 'Select an item',
        ajax: {
            url: 'select2-autocomplete-ajax',
            dataType: 'json',
            delay: 250,
            processResults: function (data) {
                return {
                results:  $.map(data, function (item) {
                        return {
                            text: item.categoria,
                            id: item.id
                        }
                    })
                };
            },
            cache: true
        }
    });

</script>
```

## Pacotes ajax

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Tente remover o `tabindex="-1"` da div do seu modal.

Comment: Cara, você é um gênio! Como teve essa sacada direta assim? Qual é a funcionalidade do "tabindex="-1" "?

Comment: Usando tabindex, pode-se especificar uma ordem explícita para elementos de página

Comment: Ja passei por esse problema anteriormente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta você remover a propriedade `tabindex="-1"` da sua div do modal. Alterando:

```
<div id="modal" class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
```

Por:

```
<div id="modal" class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" role="dialog">
```

**TabIndex**

A propriedade `tabindex` recebe um valor inteiro que determina se o elemento pode receber o foco na entrada dos dados, determinando uma ordem para os elementos.
Utilizando o `tabindex="-1"`, ou seja, um valor negativo o elemento não receberá o foco quando o tab é pressionado.

Funcionamento do tabindex (Pressionando o tab a ordem de foco é determinada e os valores que são negativos não são utilizados)

```html
<form>  
    <label>1: <input type="text" tabindex="1"/></label>  
    <p/>  
    <label>-1: <input type="text" tabindex="-1"/></label>  
    </p>  
    <label>2: <input type="text" tabindex="2"/></label>  
    </p>  
    <input type="submit" tabindex="3"/>  
</form>
```